# Possession with the noun "need"

Tags: grammar, possessives

I am writing a open paper (formal writing) but I don't know what is the correct usage of grammar for the phase:

> The journal's needs for “impact” and to follow hot topics...

or

> The needs of journals for “impact” and to follow hot topics...

*Thanks.*

Comment: Much depends on whether you're talking about *one* journal or several. Also, even though there's a need for "impact" ***and*** a need to follow hot topics, native speakers would normally use the singular form to cover both: *"A man's **need** for food and water will usually override his moral sensibilities"*.

Comment: So, in the case of multiples journals
> The need of journals for “impact” and to follow hot topics,

Comment: Also, the lack of balance in having first a noun and then an infinitive is clunky. “The journal’s need to have ‘impact’ and follow hot topics…” sounds much more balanced and flows better. Or even more idiomatic: “The need for journals to have ‘impact’ and follow hot topics…”.

Answer (score 1):

Your first usage is incorrect. *The journal's needs* is a plural noun. It seems as if you're looking to use *need* as a verb. Furthermore, your parallel sentence structure sounds awkward with both a noun and an infinitive. Choose one and then have them both conform:

> The journal needs "impact" and hot topics.

Or

> The journal needs to be impactful and to follow hot topics.

Comment: One need never stoop so low as to resort to uglinesses like *impactful*.

Comment: @tchrist *be impacting*? *bear impact*? *pack a punch*?